# Cant get .ajax to give a value when posting to controller in .net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm using .ajax to post an object back to my controller, but whatever I do it doesn't seem to work. Its weird because I've pretty much used this code on other projects and its worked fine. I can get the .ajax to post to the contoller but the object array comes back empty. If anyone can give me an idea of how to fix, that would be great.

```js
function getFilterProducts(SelectedFeatures) {
                var urlFeaturesFilter = '@Url.ActionLink("GetFilteredProductsByFeature", "Home")';

                var selectedfeatures = []

                let thistring = {Id: "1"}
                selectedfeatures.push(thistring);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ selectedfeatures }),
                    url: "Home/GetFilteredProductsByFeature",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("Error: Failed to close country.");

                    }
                })

            }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFilteredProductsByFeature(List<ProductFeaturesVM> selectedfeatures)
    {

        return Json(selectedfeatures);

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a pattern matching issue. My reccomentation is change the return type to 'IActionResult' then change the return statement from return Json(selectedfeatures), to return Ok(selectedfeatures). See how that goes

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham I've just tried this and no luck. selectedfeatures is still showing as empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Id` in your `ProductFeaturesVM` is `int`,

you need to change you ajax like follow(Remove the double quotes of "1" and modify data):

```
function getFilterProducts(SelectedFeatures) {
            var urlFeaturesFilter = '@Url.ActionLink("GetFilteredProductsByFeature", "Home")';

            var selectedfeatures = []

            let thistring = {Id: 1}
            selectedfeatures.push(thistring);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedfeatures),
                url: "Home/GetFilteredProductsByFeature",
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error: Failed to close country.");

                }
            })

        }
```

Then in your Action,add `[FromBody]`:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFilteredProductsByFeature([FromBody]List<ProductFeaturesVM> selectedfeatures)
{

    return Json(selectedfeatures);

}
```

If the Id in your `ProductFeaturesVM` is `string`,just add the double quotes back.

Comment: This worked thanks! The  [FromBody] was the catalyst, I had previously tried the other changes.